# Why does `let` modify the value it assigns?

Tags: vim

I run this in command mode:

```
let @a="^M"
reg a
```

I see this as output:

```
--- Registers ---
"a   ^M^J
```

Why is there an extra `^J`? Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy some text into registers using `v`, `V`, and `<c-v>` visual modes to see how Vim handles each situation.

To force a specific mode (I am going to assume `v`) use `setreg()`.

```
:call setreg('a', '^M', 'v')
```

For more help see

```
:h setreg(
```

Answer (score 0):

`^M` is the carriage return character. `^J` is the line feed character. Windows uses carriage return followed by a line feed (`^M^J`) to represent a newline. So I assume this is where it is coming from. Not sure about the why? yet.